# Can't run Gatsy project on UBUNTU

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gatsby, npm-install

I'm developing Gatsby project and try to run it on UBUNTU system. I have such ERROR when trying to run "npm install". This project I cloned from git repository. On Windows it works correctly and I can run it with "gatsby develop", but in UBUNTU it throw such error....
How can I manage it?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/grerin/Omertex/website/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install --runtime=napi) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! info sharp Using cached /home/grerin/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.9.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.8.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/home/grerin/Omertex/website/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/home/grerin/Omertex/website/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/home/grerin/Omertex/website/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/home/grerin/Omertex/website/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/grerin/Omertex/website/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/grerin/Omertex/website/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/grerin/Omertex/website/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:196:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-41-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/grerin/Omertex/website/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/grerin/Omertex/website/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/grerin/.npm/_logs/2021-02-05T07_45_41_662Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is:

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

Gatsby and some of their dependencies and transformers ([`sharp`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sharp/), `transformer-sharp`, mostly for image processing) are coded in Python so it's a mandatory dependency.

In Windows, because of the [`windows-build-tools`](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) the Python dependency it's added automatically so if you have cloned the repo from a Windows-based installation, you need to set up Python.

Try running:

```
npm uninstall node-gyp -g
npm config set python python2.7
npm config set msvs_version 2015
npm cache clean -f
npm install
```

Alternatively, you can try [installing and setting Python](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-ubuntu) on your machine and try again the process

Comment: Thank U for answering Ferran!
I udate python version, but still have the same ERROR

npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.8.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python3.8.5", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

Comment: Have you installed `node-gyp`?

Comment: I'm trying to install node-gyp, but it always fail.....
grerin@Omertex:~$ sudo apt install node-gyp
......
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 node-gyp : Depends: libnode-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: grerin@Omertex:~/Omertex/website$ node -v && npm -v
v14.15.4     
7.5.2
grerin@Omertex:~/Omertex/website$ node-gyp --version
v7.1.2
Install node-gyp, but got the same error.